# Spring 3 MVC: Show validation message with custom validator

Tags: model-view-controller, spring, validation, jsp

I need help. I am beginner in jsp, MVC. I want to validate form input with custom validator in Spring 3 MVC.

My validator class

```
   package validators;

import models.UserModel;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.validation.Errors;
import org.springframework.validation.ValidationUtils;
import org.springframework.validation.Validator;
@Component
public class UserValidator implements Validator {

   @Override
   public boolean supports(Class clazz) {
      return UserModel.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz);
   }

   @Override
   public void validate(Object target, Errors errors) {
      ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(errors, "firstname", "Enter firstname.");
      ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(errors, "surname", "Enter surname.");
      ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(errors, "login", "Enter login.");

   }

}
```

Controller class

```
package controllers;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import models.UserModel;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import validators.UserValidator;
import database.UserDB;


@Controller
public class UserController {

@RequestMapping(value="pouzivatel/new", method=RequestMethod.POST)
   public ModelAndView newUser(@ModelAttribute UserModel user, BindingResult result){
      UserValidator validator = new UserValidator();
      validator.validate(user, result);
      if(result.hasErrors()){
         return new ModelAndView("/user/new","command",user);

      }
      ...
}
```

Model for User

```
package models;

public class UserModel  {
   private String firstname="";
   private String surname="";

   public String getFirstname() {
      return firstname;
   }
   public String getSurname() {
      return surname;
   }

   public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
      this.firstname = firstname;
   }
   public void setSurname(String surname) {
      this.surname = surname;
   }

}
```

JSP  veiw new.jsp which is in directory /web-inf/user (it just only form)

```
<form:form method="post" action="new.html">
            <fieldset>
               <table>
                  <tr>
                     <td>
                        <form:label path="firstname">FirstName</form:label>
                     </td>
                     <td>
                        <form:input path="firstname" />
                        <form:errors path="firstname" />
                     </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                     <td>
                        <form:label path="surname">Surname</form:label>
                     </td>
                     <td>
                        <form:input path="surname" />
                        <form:errors path="surname" />
                     </td>
                  </tr>
               </table>
            </fieldset>
            <div>
               <button type="submit" id="btOk">Ok</button>
            </div>
</form:form>
```

dispatcher servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

   <context:component-scan base-package="controllers" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="validators" />

   <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
      <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
      <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
      <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
   </bean>

</beans>
```

Problem is a display validation message in view. Validation is successful and in variable resut (BindingResult) are errors. Controller return follow part of code

```
if(result.hasErrors()){
         return new ModelAndView("/user/new","command",user);
```

Another way is use Annotation validation (I preffer custom validator), but why i can not see validation messages on view, when input  fields are empty.

Can you give me example how to do it right?

Thanks for reply.

Answer (score 20):

This happens because of mismatch between default model attribute names in view and controller:

- When you write `<form:form>` without `modelAttribute` (or `commandName`) attribute, it uses default model attribute name `command`.
- When you write `@ModelAttribute UserModel user` in your controller, it assumes that the name of this attribute is a decapitalized class name, i.e. `userModel`.

That is, error messages produced by validator are bound to model attribute named `userModel`, while your view tries to show errors for model attribute `command`.

You need to set a model attribute name explicitly, either in the view (`<form:form modelAttribute = "userModel" ...>`) or in the controller (`@ModelAttribute("command")`).