# spring 3 validation example

Tags: spring, validation

Can anybody give me a link for Spring 3.0 Validation, by extending `org.springframework.validation.Validator` or `javax.validation` Interface and reading error messages from properties file?

Thanks
Shams

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a good link to start with Spring 3 validation
    [Spring 3 MVC: Show validation message with custom validator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4031266/spring-3-mvc-show-validation-message-with-custom-validator).

for reading properties file use:

```
ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmpty(errors, "userId", "field.required");
```

in Validation class. and using

```
<bean id="messageSource"
        class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basename" value = "messages" />
    </bean>
```

in dispatcher-servlet.xml file to load message.properties file.

And it is working fine..
Cheers
Shams

Answer (score 0):

```
public class LoginValidator implements Validator {

    public boolean supports(Class aClass) {
        return Login.class.equals(aClass);
    }

    public void validate(Object obj, Errors errors) {
        Login login = (Login) obj;

        ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(errors, "userName",
                "username.required", "Required field");

        ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(errors, "userPassword",
                "userpassword.required", "Required field");
    }

}
```