# Spring MVC 3 Validator not displaying Error Message

Tags: java, forms, jsp, spring-mvc, tiles

I have problem with displaying error message in spring Application.i am using Spring MVC 3 and Apache Tiles. when i am having error in form than it will not displays error message.
please help me hear is the piece of code.

Web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>SpringExample</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>
                /WEB-INF/spring/dispatcher-servlet.xml
            </param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>  

</web-app>
```

dispatcher-Servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.examples.spring" />


    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass">
            <value>
                org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesView
            </value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="tilesConfigurer"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesConfigurer">
        <property name="definitions">
            <list>
                <value>/WEB-INF/tiles.xml</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>


</beans>
```

tiles.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE tiles-definitions PUBLIC
       "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Tiles Configuration 2.0//EN"
       "http://tiles.apache.org/dtds/tiles-config_2_0.dtd">
<tiles-definitions>


    <definition name="create_account_success" template="/WEB-INF/jsp/account/SuccessJSP.jsp">
    </definition>

    <definition name="account_create" template="/WEB-INF/jsp/account/testForm.jsp">

    </definition>


</tiles-definitions>
```

testForm.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
    <%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form:form id="form" modelAttribute="formCreate" method="post">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Name :</td>
            <td><form:input path="name"/>
                <form:errors path="name"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Password :</td>
            <td><form:input path="password"/>
                <form:errors path="password"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </form:form>
</body>
</html>
```

AccountRegistrationController.java

```
package com.examples.spring.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import com.examples.spring.dto.AccountDTO;
import com.examples.spring.validator.AccountValidator;

@Controller
public class AccountRegistrationController {


    public static final String BASE_URL = "/account";

    @RequestMapping(value = BASE_URL + "/create" ,method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView accountCreate(){
        ModelAndView view = new ModelAndView();
        view.addObject("formCreate", new AccountDTO());
        view.setViewName("account_create");
        return view;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = BASE_URL + "/create" ,method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView accountRegistration(@ModelAttribute AccountDTO accountDTO,BindingResult result ){

        ModelAndView view = new ModelAndView();

        AccountValidator validator = new AccountValidator();
        validator.validate(accountDTO, result);
        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            view.setViewName("account_create");
            view.addObject("formCreate", accountDTO);
            return view;
        }
        view.setViewName("create_account_success");
        return view;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = BASE_URL + "/login" ,method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView accountLogin(){
        ModelAndView view = new ModelAndView();
        view.setViewName("account_login");
        return view;
    }
}
```

AccountValidator.java

```
package com.examples.spring.validator;

import org.springframework.validation.Errors;
import org.springframework.validation.ValidationUtils;
import org.springframework.validation.Validator;

import com.examples.spring.dto.AccountDTO;

public class AccountValidator implements Validator {

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> clazz) {
        return AccountDTO.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz);
    }

    @Override
    public void validate(Object result, Errors error) {
        AccountDTO accountDTO = (AccountDTO) result;

        ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmpty(error, "name", "require.name", "Name Requires.");
        ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmpty(error, "password", "require.password", "Password Requires.");
    }

}
```

AccountDTO.java

```
package com.examples.spring.dto;

public class AccountDTO {


    private String name;
    private String password;

    public AccountDTO() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }
    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

}
```

My Code is working well but it does not displays error messages in `<form:errors />`.

please help me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Spring 3 MVC: Show validation message with custom validator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4031266/spring-3-mvc-show-validation-message-with-custom-validator)

Comment: thanks axtvat this link help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The third parameter to ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmpty is an error code.  It should be a key to the actual message in your resource bundle.  I don't know how it behaves if it can't find a value.  You should change it to use a key, and optionally set a default message.  See the [api](http://javasourcecode.org/html/open-source/spring/spring-3.0.5/org/springframework/validation/ValidationUtils.html).

Comment: i have been tried with 'ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmpty(error, "name", "require.name", "Name Requires.");
  ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmpty(error, "password", "require.password", "Password Requires."); ' also but still it not working

Comment: i have to set `@ModelAttribute("formCreate")` in a controller than only it will display error message.

Answer (score 1):

You need to register your validator with the controller in which you want to use it. See: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.0.RC3/reference/html/ch05s07.html#validation.mvc